# Unwanted anchor tag using twitter bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I'm using twitter bootstrap (not sure if that's the issue but it might be worth mentioning) and wordpress. This is a custom page and I wrote it entirely using the html editor (nothing was done with the wysiwyg editor)

I want to do a clickable thumbnail that is followed by a caption

```
<li class="span4">
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="#">
<center><img alt="" src="[acf field='thumb1']" /></center>
<h3>Mobilier de Bureau</h3>
</a>
Nous avons un vaste choix de mobilier de bureau pour tous types de besoins. Notre premier objectif: fournir un mobilier de bureau de qualité, assorti d'un service après-vente personnalisé. Les meubles montrés sur notre site ne sont qu'une infime partie de ce que nous pouvons vous proposer. N'hésitez pas à nous contacter. S'il vous faut un mobilier, nous l'avons.
</li>
```

But when I go to my page, I get a strange unwanted anchor tag that comes from nowhere:

```
<li class="span4">
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="#">
<center>
<img alt="" src="http://www.jeango.net/burama/assets/mobilier.png"/>
</center>
<p/>
<h3>Mobilier de Bureau</h3>
</a>
<p>
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="#"/> <------------ Unwanted anchor
<br/>
Nous avons un vaste choix de mobilier de bureau pour tous types de besoins. Notre premier objectif: fournir un mobilier de bureau de qualité, assorti d’un service après-vente personnalisé. Les meubles montrés sur notre site ne sont qu’une infime partie de ce que nous pouvons vous proposer. N’hésitez pas à nous contacter. S’il vous faut un mobilier, nous l’avons.
</p>
</li>
```

Comment: where's `<p>` come from? nowhere too?

Comment: yeah, comes from nowhere. I guess it's wordpress doing some shenanigans. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

But wpautop() doesn't explain the extra anchor

Comment: I've had this problem before and I've found it's easier to create a custom page template rather than try to battle the HTML editor. Are you on WP 3.5.1?

Comment: Yeah,
eventually I just re-did the whole page anew, and it solved the problem.